# Python: How to get number without scientific notation

Tags: python, scientific-notation

By doing this:

```
j = pow(p1, k1)
```

I get this:

```
j: 2.128e-100
```

How can I display it without the scientific notation? Something like this:

```
j: 2.128
```

Comment: `2.128` isn't what the number actually is, though. You could format it, but without that notation there are a lot of zeros.

Comment: yeah I know, but isn't there any way to just get the number and ignore the zeros? (i'm sorry, i'm still learning python)

Answer (score 2):

You can use string formatting:

```
>>> print('{:.103f}'.format(2.128e-100))
0.0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002128
```

Comment: thanks but I was hoping something to get me rid of the zeros. Is that possible? To just get the number without all the zeros?

Comment: @catinthenet: if your don't want zeros, just use scientific notation.